# How can I programmatically unselect "View published content" checkbox for anonymous users?

Tags: users

I am using Drupal 8. I want to programmatically unselect the *View published content* checkbox for anonymous users.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert this code in a hook_install() or hook_update() :

```
$role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::load('anonymous');
$role->revokePermission('your_permission');
$role->save();
```

Comment: $role = \Drupal\user\Entity\Role::load('anonymous');
$role->revokePermission('view published content');
$role->save();

Comment: I have checked in hook_install but it is not working ...

Comment: The option is still checked for Anonymous user ..

Comment: Did you uninstall/reinstall your module ? Your hook_install is in .install file ?

Comment: Actually the machine readable name for "View published content" is "access content"
I have changed my code now it works like a charm ... Thanks a lot.
$role->revokePermission('access content');